# Can't make ListItems Visible

Tags: wpf, linq, listview

I have 3 ListViews in a WPF Grid Column, one each for customers, products, and vendors.

They each get data from LINQs to separate SS2005 queries in the same DB.
The lists are populated when a user enters text in a `TextBox`.
The LINQ query code uses as `startswith()` function that reads the user entry and returns a smaller list to the ListView.

When the code is run, each `ListView` is populated properly.
However, the Products list doesn't display the entries.
I attached a call to a `MessageBox` to the selection event of the ListItem and the message box correctly displays the product.

The single difference between the two working lists and the bad one is the query that calls the bad one returns a single field from the DB and the others return two fields, a text field and an integer ID field.

I'm at a loss.
The background of the ListView is white, the foreground is black (they were set using the properties panel).

Comment: can you post the XAML for your listboxes?

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I should have gotten back to this more expeditiously. 

It turned out to be a non-problem. I had (omitted or deleted) a single line of code from the non-working instance. 

I guess I stayed away 'coz I was too embarrassed to 'fess up.

Comment: are you using binding for listbox itemssource ?